# JSF: Validation for Special characters

Tags: regex, validation, jsf

I want to apply validation for Special characters like `(,/'#~@[]}{+_)(*&^%$£"!\|<>)`
using the jsf validator. i have implemented the validator for number but now i want to make validator for Special characters.

```
value.toString().trim().matches();
```

What will be the regular expression inside the `matches()` method in java class?

i want to allow all the field excluding the specified characters.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just *allow* alphanumerical characters *only*?

```
if (!value.toString().trim().matches("\\p{Alnum}*")) {
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Invalid characters!"));
}
```

If you really want to go ahead in this direction. To check if the string contains those characters, use this:

```
if (value.toString().trim().matches(".*[,/'#~@\\x5B\\x5D}{+_)(*&^%$£\"!\\|<>]+.*")) {
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Invalid characters!"));
}
```

Keep in mind that there are much more characters available in the Unicode charset you'd probably also like to disallow.

Comment: Hi,Balus thanx 4 reply...but i want to restrict only the listing characters...all others will be allowed...(i.e. "." and white spaces ,etc.. are allowed)

Comment: How about the million other characters in [Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm)? You'd rather like to match on **allowed** chars, not on *disallowed* chars.

Comment: Hi Balus...can we display this message from message.property file ?

Comment: @BalusC please how to allow numbers and + sign only ?? please reply ?